# How to add role to group using constructor

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, roles, usergroups

I've been tried to set role to every group while they are creating. I thought using __constructor will be good idea, but it doesn't work, ROLE_ADMIN isn't in new groups. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Group.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group as BaseGroup;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GroupRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="d0s_groups")
 */
class Group extends BaseGroup
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(
     *     message="Nazwa grupy nie może być pusta."
     * )
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 32,
     *      minMessage = "Nazwa grupy musi mieć conajmniej 3 znaki.",
     *      maxMessage = "Nazwa grupy może mieć maksymalnie 32 znaki."
     * )
     */
    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name, $roles = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $roles);
        $this->addRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you actually call the constructor? if not, doctrine does usually NOT call the constructor of entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the documentation says it best:

> The constructor of an entity is only ever invoked when ***you*** construct a new instance with the **`new`** keyword. Doctrine never calls entity constructors, thus you are free to use them as you wish and even have it require arguments of any type.

source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/architecture.html

So essentially, unless you actually *store* the roles in the database, your constructor is irrelevant when an object is loaded from db. There are ways around this, you could override your `getRoles` method to add the additional role there.